# Conversión from Julian to gregorian Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using bigquery function `parse_date` with format `%y%j`, like this:

```
parse_date('%y%j', '18242')
```

, but this is returning `2018-01-01`, it looks like is not taking the day, when I used the same format to convert from gregorian to julian with the fuction `format_date('%y%j', '2018-08-30')` and returns the value `18242`.

Anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

The query used is:

```
SELECT  format_date('%y%j', date '2018-08-30') as test2
        , parse_date('%y%j', '18242') test3
```

The result:

```
test2 = '18242'
test3 = '2018-01-01'
```

Comment: this is 100% duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/57751860/5221944

Comment: It is not 100% the same. The format of the date is different! If you take the answer from this post as stackoverflow.com/q/57751860/5221944 and execute it would not give the expected results.

Comment: @StéphaneFréchette - replacing `Y` with `y` still makes it quite a copy paste - so I would rather reference that answer and add few words comments - that is how I would do. But obviously you are free to do whatever you think is right to do

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat a duplicate question. The answer can be found here in another post see [stackoverflow.com/a/57761150/5221944](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57761150/5221944)

What you need to change is the formatting by replacing %Y with %y

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It works perfect!

Comment: that was nice copy-paste from https://stackoverflow.com/a/57761150/5221944. usually this is not how we do it here on SO. you could just mark / comment that this question as a duplicate!!!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant agree but not completely! Question relates to different formatting on the year (%y instead of %Y) and would give different results than the one expected by the user asking the question